# How to use Checkbox checked value in C# ASP.Net MVC

Tags: c#, angular, asp.net-mvc, checkbox

I'm new to ASP.Net so any help greatly appreciated.

I've added a checkbox to a page, to choose between including archived customers or not:

```
    <form>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="col-lg-3 control-label">Include Archived Customers</label>
                <div class="col-lg-9">
                    <input class="form-control" style="transform:scale(0.5)" type="checkbox" ng-model="includeArchived" ng-change="includeFlagsChanged()" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
```

This is the script that I've tried to add to:

```
<script>
    var app = angular.module("InvAggApp", ['angular-loading-bar']);
    app.controller("customerLinkController", function ($scope, $http) {
        $scope.includeArchived = false;
        $http.get("/DataLink/CheckForXeroToken")
            .then(function (response) {
                $scope.response = response;
                if (response.data.Success) {
                    $scope.hasXeroToken = response.data.hasXeroToken;
                    if ($scope.hasXeroToken) initialise();
                } else {
                    $scope.error = response.data.Exception;
                }
            }, function (response) { $scope.error = response });

        var initialise = function () {
            $http.post("/DataLink/GetCustomerLinks")
                .then(function (response) {
                    includeArchived: $scope.includeArchived
                    $scope.error = null;
                    $scope.response = response;
                    if (response.data.Success) {
                        $scope.customers = response.data.customers;
                        $scope.wcCustomers = response.data.wcCustomers;
                    } else {
                        $scope.error = response.data.Exception;
                    }
                }, function (response) { $scope.error = response });
        }

        debugger;
        $scope.includeFlagsChanged = function () {
            $scope.includeArchived = includeArchived;            
        };
```

Then this where I need to use it, I'm wanting to replace the .Where(xc => xc.archived == false) to use the includeArchived value of checkbox

```
public async Task<JsonResult> GetCustomerLinks() {
            try {
                var xeroSession = new XeroSessionManager();
                var xeroData = new XeroData(xeroSession);
                var xeroCustomers = await xeroData.GetAllCustomers();
                
                using (var cx = new BillingAssistantContext()) {
                    var wcCustomers = cx.Companies.Select(c => new { wcId = c.ID, wcName = c.Name }).OrderBy(c => c.wcName).ToArray();
                    var customers = xeroCustomers.Select(xc => {
                        var cl = cx.CustomerLinks.SingleOrDefault(l => l.XeroContactID == xc.ContactID);
                        return new {
                            xeroId = xc.ContactID, xeroName = xc.Name,
                            wcCustomerId = cl?.WCompanyID,
                            archived = cl?.Archived
                        };
                    }).Where(xc => xc.archived == false).OrderBy(xc => xc.xeroName).ToArray();

                    return new JsonResult {
                        Data = new {
                            Success = true,
                            customers = customers,
                            wcCustomers = wcCustomers,
                        }
                    };
                }
```

Comment: Add a bool parameter to the `GetCustomerLinks` endpoint, and pass your includeArchived value when calling that endpoint.

Comment: Thank you I've added that in, sorry I wasn't very clear though. it's the triggering of the script $http.post('/DataLink/GetCustomerLinks', again on the check event of the checkbox that I'm not sure with

Comment: Have you tried calling `initialise()` from within the `includeFlagsChanged` function?

Comment: Thanks very much for your help all working